# How can I return true or false based on a string based expression in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm needing to create a dynamic validator based on a string value that's passed into a json object. So let's say you have the following string:

```
var required: "Homes > 0"
```

In this example, "Homes" is an accessible object within my function. I want to logically turn the above into:

```
if (this.Homes > 0) { return true; }
```

Thinking about this in parts:

```
if (this[left] > parsed[right]) { return true; }
```

I think you get the idea. I'm not sure if there's a way to easily extract operators without just doing a switch for every type? As in:

```
required: "Homes = 0" // this[Left] === 0
```

I'm about to do this in a very horrifying ugly string splitting way with a switch case on the operators. Was just wondering if there was a super slick way to make something like this robust.

Comment: What if instead of a string you accept a function: `var required = function(o) { return o.Homes > 0; };`?

Comment: Hmm. Well I'm going to try that right now. My initial goal was to make it human friendly in a string format.

Comment: You either have to write your own parser, or use someone else's. *eval* and the *Function* constructor give you access to the built–in parser. You can also insert code as the content of a script node. Take your pick.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

```
eval('Homes > 0');
```

but please consider using this pattern instead:

```
function Class(){
     this.validate = function(){
         return true;
     }
}

var x = new Class();
//overload the validate operator
x.validate = function(){
    return false;
}
```

You want to avoid eval because it is potentially unsafe because it allows for arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
eval("if (this.Homes > 0) { return true; }");
```

Comment: eval is fundamentally insecure :(